# how to get nested object value

Tags: javascript, json

I'm stuck on something simple. The code below will give "3" as the result...however. I want to get three without having to explicitly know "New York"?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>JavaScript Objects</h2>
<p>Display object properties:</p>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
const person = {
  city: {"New York":3}
};

let txt = "";
for (let x in person) {
  txt += person[x]["New York"] + " ";  <----how to get 3 without "New York" explicitly stated
};

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

How can I pull this off. I promise I'll put this nested object question in my personal notes so I won't forget it again.

Comment: Why not the same type of loop you’ve got for `person`? `for (let y in person[x])`

Comment: @esqew I'm not clear on what you are saying. Are you saying to do a nested loop? Cause I'm wondering of there is just some object or dot notation that can be done on the indicated line?

Comment: `Object.values(person[x])[0]` perhaps? If you only have one property in each sub-object

Comment: @Nick I think that's it. If you put your solution as an answer posted below, I'll credit you for it.

Comment: Note that this type of nested structure is an anti-pattern. Don't use dynamic property names unless the intent is to use the names as a lookup table. Use something like `{name: "New York", value: 3}`

Comment: @thefonso it seems a lot of other people already copied that comment to an answer...

Comment: @Nick yes. But the solution was yours first. So if you want credit it is yours else I'll pick from the others.

Comment: @thefonso that's fine I don't need the rep. Happy you have a working solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without additional context, it's unclear what you mean by the "New York" key changing. Assuming that the city object will always have one key and you need to extract the value of that key, you can iterate over the keys of the object using a for...in loop, and extract the value using the Object.values() method:

```js
const person = {
  city: {"New York": 3}
};

let txt = "";
for (let x in person) {
  txt += Object.values(person[x])[0] + " ";
}

console.log(txt); // Output: 3
```

Comment: You should give credit to @Nick in your answer if you are copying their comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Object.values retrieves the values in an object as an array (omitting the keys). Since you only seem to have one key in the object city there will only be on value in that array (index 0), so you could do:

```js
    const person = {
      city: { "New York": 3 }
    };
    
    console.log(Object.values(person.city)[0]);
```